# ¿Qué pasa con este codigo?

Tags: c, vscode

En concreto la función 'introducir datos' es para que el usuario introduzca los datos de una persona, el caso es que a la hora de comprobar que el nombre es válido, la función me dice que es válido justo antes
de un while al que se entra solo si es inválido, sin embargo aun así entra.

Aquí esta el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// tipos definidos
typedef struct persona persona;
//  macros
#undef NULL
#define NULL 0
#define NOMBRE_DE_FICHERO "BDD"
#define ESPACIO 32
// prototipos
void menuInicial();
void limpiarCadena(char cadenaAlimpiar[]);
void introducirDatos();
void VerDatos();
void eliminarDatos();
void clrscr();
void gotoxy(int x, int y);
void agregarAfichero(persona *personaNueva);
bool comprobarValidezDeEleccion(char eleccion[], int opcionMayor, int opcionMenor, int cantidadDeCaracteresDeLaOpcion);
bool comprobarEdad(char nombre[]);
bool comprobarNombre(char edad[]);
// cuerpo de funciones y estructuras
struct persona
{
    char nombre[50];
    char correoElectronico[40];
    char direccion[40];
    char edad[3];
};
void menuInicial()
{
    char eleccion[20];
    printf("\n\n\n\t\tHola, que deseas hacer?\n\n\t");
    printf("a)  Introducir datos de personas\n\t");
    printf("b)  Ver datos de una persona\n\t");
    printf("c)  Eliminar datos de una persona\n\t");
    printf("d)  Salir\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t");
    printf("Introduce tu eleccion aqui ==> ");
    gets(eleccion);
    while (comprobarValidezDeEleccion(eleccion, 100, 97, 1) == false)
    {
        printf("\n\n\n\t\tHola, que deseas hacer?\n\n\t");
        printf("a)  Introducir datos de personas\n\t");
        printf("b)  Ver datos de una persona\n\t");
        printf("c)  Eliminar datos de una persona\n\t");
        printf("d)  Salir\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t");
        printf("Has seleccionado una opcion invalida, intentalo de nuevo ==> ");
        limpiarCadena(eleccion);
        gets(eleccion);
    }
    switch (eleccion[0])
    {
    case 97:
        introducirDatos();
        break;
    case 98:
        VerDatos();
        break;
    case 99:
        eliminarDatos();
        break;
    default:
        exit(-1);
    }
}
bool comprobarValidezDeEleccion(char eleccion[], int opcionMayor, int opcionMenor, int cantidadDeCaracteresDeLaOpcion)
{
    int i, longitudDeCadena;
    if (strlen(eleccion) == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (strlen(eleccion) > NULL)
        {
            longitudDeCadena = strlen(eleccion);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < longitudDeCadena; i++)
    {
        if (eleccion[i] == NULL || eleccion[cantidadDeCaracteresDeLaOpcion] > NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (eleccion[i] < opcionMenor || eleccion[i] > opcionMayor)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
void limpiarCadena(char cadenaAlimpiar[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(cadenaAlimpiar); i++)
    {
        if (cadenaAlimpiar[i] != NULL)
        {
            cadenaAlimpiar[i] = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            if (cadenaAlimpiar[i] == NULL)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
void introducirDatos()
{
    persona *personaActual;
    personaActual = (persona *)malloc(sizeof(persona));
    printf("\n\n\t\tIntroduce el nombre de tu usuario  ==> ");
    gets(personaActual->nombre);
    if (comprobarNombre(personaActual->nombre) == true)
    {
        printf("La cadena es valida");
    }
    else
    { // este condicional anidado lo hice por desesperacion y se confirmaron mis sospechas
        if (comprobarNombre(personaActual->nombre) == false)
        {
            printf("La cadena no es valida");
        }
    }
    while (comprobarNombre(personaActual->nombre) == false) // la cadena es valida antes de entrar pero no lo es al hacerlo
    {
        printf("\t\tHas introducido un nombre invalido, intentalo de nuevo  ==> ");
        limpiarCadena(personaActual->nombre);
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(personaActual->nombre);
    }
    printf("\t\tIntroduce la edad de el usuario  ==> ");
    gets(personaActual->edad);
    while (comprobarEdad(personaActual->edad) == false)
    {
        printf("\t\tHas introducido una edad invalida, intentalo de nuevo  ==> ");
        limpiarCadena(personaActual->edad);
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(personaActual->edad);
    }
    printf("\t\tIntroduce la direccion del usuario  ==> ");
    gets(personaActual->direccion);
    printf("\n\nIntroduce el correo electronico del usuario ==> ");
    gets(personaActual->correoElectronico);
    agregarAfichero(personaActual);
}
void VerDatos()
{
}
void eliminarDatos() // estas son funciones futuras, no tienen repercusion alguna
{
}
bool comprobarEdad(char edad[])
{
    int longitudDeEdad = strlen(edad);
    int i;
    if (longitudDeEdad > 3 || edad[0] == 32 || edad[0] == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < longitudDeEdad; i++)
    {
        if (edad[i] < 48 || edad[i] > 57)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
bool comprobarNombre(char nombre[])
{
    int i;
    if (nombre[0] == NULL || nombre[0] == ESPACIO || strlen(nombre) < 8)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(nombre); i++)
    {
        if ((nombre[i] >= 97 && nombre[i] <= 122) || (nombre[i] >= 65 && nombre[i] <= 90) || (nombre[i] == 32))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            if ((nombre[i] > 0 && nombre[i] < 65) || (nombre[i] > 90 && nombre[i] < 97) || (nombre[i] > 122))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
void agregarAfichero(persona *personaNueva)
{
    FILE *fichero;
    fichero = fopen(NOMBRE_DE_FICHERO, "a");
    fprintf(fichero, "%s\n", personaNueva->nombre);
    fprintf(fichero, "%s\n", personaNueva->edad);
    fprintf(fichero, "%s\n", personaNueva->direccion);
    fprintf(fichero, "%s\n", personaNueva->correoElectronico);
    fclose(fichero);
    fflush(fichero);
}
```

Estoy ejecutando el programa desde `powrshell` en concreto el que me brinda `vs code`, es ahi donde programo. Por otro lado, destacar que en algunos puntos agregue un `fflush(stdin)` se que no es eficiente, estoy desesperado. Como ya mencione el programa es una base de datos sencilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Bienvenido a la comunidad!

Te responderé con una pregunta: ¿Porqué tu función "comprobarNombre" no retorna true?

Veo los return con el false, pero no veo un solo return true, esto podría ocacionar problemas de ejecución.
**Intenta** agregarle que retorne "true" hasta llegar al final, tras "sobrevivir" a todas las validaciones que podrían lanzar "false".

**Ejemplo**

```
bool comprobarNombre(char nombre[])
{
    int i;
    if (nombre[0] == NULL || nombre[0] == ESPACIO || strlen(nombre) < 8)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(nombre); i++)
    {
        if ((nombre[i] >= 97 && nombre[i] <= 122) || (nombre[i] >= 65 && nombre[i] <= 90) || (nombre[i] == 32))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            if ((nombre[i] > 0 && nombre[i] < 65) || (nombre[i] > 90 && nombre[i] < 97) || (nombre[i] > 122))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true; // Acá deberías retornar que es válido según mi opinión.
}
```

Comment: Gracias, supongo que estaba algo despistado, ya funciono.

Comment: Tranquilo, recuerda que los desarrolladores somos criaturas que tras estar concentrados en problemas complejos, los asuntos "pequeños" se nos escapan ;)